# Holomorphic function and uniform convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I am given the following problem:

Let $f\colon G\to \mathbb{C}$ be a complex function where $G$ is open and not empty. Assume that $(f_n)$ converges locally uniformly to $f$ and $f_n$ is complex differentiable (holomorphic) for all $n$. Prove that $f$ is also complex differentiable (holomorphic) and that $f'_n$ converges locally uniformly to $f'$.

I struggle with proving this rigorously though it appears intuitively correct. I ask for help

Comment: The Cauchy integral formula is quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Morera's theorem, a function is holomorphic on a disc iff the integral over any triangle is zero.  Since this holds for $f_n$ and we have uniform convergence, it is easy to show the same for $f$.

For convergence of $f_n'$, use the integral representation given by the Cauchy integral formula.